# convert list into string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Here is my list `['k:1','d:2','k:3','z:0']` now I want to remove apostrophes from list item and store it in the string form like `'k:1 , d:2, k:3, z:0'` Here is my code

```
nlist = ['k:1','d:2','k:3','z:0']
newlist = []
for x in nlist:
  kk = x.strip("'")
  newlist.append(kk)
```

This code still give me the same thing

Comment: You sound a bit confused as to how strings are represented.

Comment: The items in the list are Strings. The apostrophes denote the start and end of each strings, but aren't actually in the strings themselves. You should `print(x)` in your for loop, which will print each element in the list on a line.

Comment: The `'` is not part of the string and thus it is not something you can remove from it.

Comment: I corrected my question please reconsider it Thankyou @darcamo,@the_storyteller,@Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this : `print(', '.join(['k:1','d:2','k:3','z:0']))`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to see them without the apostrophes, try to print one of them alone.

try this:

`print(nlist[0])`
`output: k:1`

you can see that apostrophes because it's inside a list, when you call the value alone the text comes clean.

I would recommend studying more about strings, it's very fundamental to know how they work.

Answer (score 0):

The parenthesis comes from the way of representing a `list`, to know wether an element is a string or not, quotes are used

```
print(['aStr', False, 5]) # ['aStr', False, 5]
```

---

To pass from `['k:1','d:2','k:3','z:0']` to  `k:1 , d:2, k:3, z:0` you need to join the elements.

```
values = ['k:1','d:2','k:3','z:0']
value = ", ".join(values)
print(value)  # k:1, d:2, k:3, z:0
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a list of strings and you want to join them into a single string.

This can be done with `", ".join(['k:1','d:2','k:3','z:0'])`.